# Вставка слов в разметку

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть матрица 0 - пустое место 1 - место куда можно вставить букву. и массив со словами например слова будут такие:

кошка,собака,крот

матрица у нас например вида:

```
000000000000
000010000000
000111111000
000010000000
000011110000
000010000000
000000000000
```

после необходимых операций, которые я не знаю как реализовать, мы получим что-то вроде:

```
000000000000
0000к0000000
000собака000
0000ш0000000
0000крот0000
0000а0000000
000000000000
```

Этот пример простой потому что длина у всех слов разная. но если например у нас несколько слов одинаковой длины. Необходимо будет примерять слова и снимать слова. Есть идея сначала матрицу проходить по горизонтали а потом по вертикале, искать места куда можно вставить слово, и если это возможно вставить, а потом идти дальше, но опять таки слова у нас могут быть абсолютно все одинаковой длины, и данный способ по моим предположениям может откинуть адекватную разметку поля (где при правильном выборе места под слова кроссворд сложится).

Comment: В чем вопрос, вы просите написать программу за вас?

Comment: @KromStern если бы я хотел чтобы за меня написали программу я пошел бы на киберфорум, если вы не прочли до конца вопрос, то там сама суть вопроса понять принцип как это реализовать, спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Вот пожалуйста и сформулируйте свой вопрос в виде вопроса )

Comment: люблю когда многие не читают вопроса и минусуют думая что этот вопрос из разряда - "сделай за меня"

Comment: Я, например, ваш вопрос прочитал и дал вам совет - сформулировать его получше. Как видно и другим ваш вопрос показался размытым и даже достойным минуса ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-нибудь в таком роде:

```
class Matrix;
class WordList;
class Word;

void fillMatrix(Matrix &m, WordList &words) {
    if (!m.filled() && m.possibleToFill()) {
        int length = m.findFirstEmptyWord();
        WordList such_length = words.getWordsByLength(length);
        for (int i=0; i<such_length.length(); i++) {
            Word w = such_length[i];
            if (m.fillFirstWord(w)) {
                words.removeWord(w);
                fillMatrix(m, words);
            }
        }
        m.setFillPossible(false);
    }
}
```

Наверняка это самый неэффективный алгоритм, но, пожалуй, самый простой в реализации. Детали реализации классов Matrix, WordList, Word - думаю, не слишком сложны.